# Programmatically create Media Wiki pages using C#

Tags: c#, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I have installed a media wiki (www.mediawiki.org) on my server and need to create Wiki pages automatically using c#.

Does anyone know how to programmatically create Media Wiki  pages using C#.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two C# wrappers for media wiki API:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wikiaccess/

http://dotnetwikibot.sourceforge.net/

the later can insert and modify pages, for first one I am not sure but check

Comment: When I used the command
        Site enWiki = new Site("http://en.wikipedia.org", "myBotLogin", "myPassword"); Is the myBotLogin the username for the Wiki? when I tried this I got the error 'Access to the path 'Cache' is denied'

Comment: you should get username / password from Wikipedia, and maybe Wikipedia restricted API access, don't know, google it :)

Answer (score 3):

Yep, take a look at this page: [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aClient_code)